# Show the Tabbed bar controller after log in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm new to swift so I need a bit of help. Trying to get the tabbed view controller to appear after the user logs in/signs up but not too sure how to. Any help would be great.

This is my code for the log in.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var logInButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpElements()
    }

    func setUpElements() {
        Utilities.styleTextField(emailTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(passwordTextField)
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(logInButton)
    }




    @IBAction func logInTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){ (result, error) in
            if error != nil {

                self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
            }
            else {

                let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as?
                HomeViewController

                self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to show your UITabBarController, but you shouldn't be touching your key window or your rootViewController or anything. You might push your controller onto the navigation stack if you're in [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller) or present it modally, or any of a number of things.

If you're in a Storyboard, the most common way to handle this is using segues.  Create a segue to your `HomeViewController` and give it a name (let's say it's "Home"):

```
@IBAction func logInTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){ (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier "Home": String, sender: self)
        }
}
```

---

You'll definitely want to have a look a the documentation for this:

[View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers)

[Showing and Hiding View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/showing_and_hiding_view_controllers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard, you can try with this

```
//make Constant.swift file and add this code and access anywhere in code

    let UIViewControllerUsingName : (String,String) -> UIViewController? = {storyBoardName,viewControllerId in

        return UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerId)

    }
```

Then add this line to `AppDelegate`file to access existing `AppDelegate`

```
static var shared : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

And

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){ (result, error) in

            if error != nil {

                self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
            }
            else {

                 if let homeVC = UIViewControllerUsingName("tabHome","tabHomeVC"){

                        //homeVC is your UITabBarController

                        AppDelegate.shared.window?.rootViewController = homeVC
                    }
            }
```